# Si Labs Clock builder C header file use

Tags: c, header-files

Is it legal to initialize a variable in a header file like this header file generated by clock builder?

```
#ifndef SI5351A_REVB_REG_CONFIG_HEADER
#define SI5351A_REVB_REG_CONFIG_HEADER

#define SI5351A_REVB_REG_CONFIG_NUM_REGS                57

typedef struct
{
    unsigned int address; /* 16-bit register address */
    unsigned char value; /* 8-bit register data */

} si5351a_revb_register_t;

si5351a_revb_register_t const si5351a_revb_registers[SI5351A_REVB_REG_CONFIG_NUM_REGS] =
{
    { 0x0002, 0x53 },
    { 0x0003, 0x00 },
    { 0x0007, 0x00 },

... bunch of data
};
#endif
```

Whenever I try to use this header file, I get an error

```
./si5351/Si5351A-RevB-Registers.o:(.rodata.si5351a_revb_registers+0x0): first defined here
./i2c/i2c.o:(.rodata.si5351a_revb_registers+0x0): multiple definition of `si5351a_revb_registers'
./si5351/Si5351A-RevB-Registers.o:(.rodata.si5351a_revb_registers+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

saying it is being defined multiple times. Probably because it's being included by some other files in my program.

However, if I separate the "typedef struct" by leaving it in the header, and then putting the big array definition of the

```
si5351a_revb_register_t const si5351a_revb_registers[SI5351A_REVB_REG_CONFIG_NUM_REGS] =
{
    { 0x0002, 0x53 },
    { 0x0003, 0x00 },
    { 0x0007, 0x00 },

... bunch of data
};
```

data into its own c file, which #includes the header it works.

Is there a more correct way of using a header file like this? Seems like there should be if that's the exact way it's generated to be used.

Comment: "Is it legal to initialize a variable in a header file", yes but do not do that.  Better to _declare_ in .h and _define_ in a .c file.

Comment: Can you think of any reason why the programmers of clock builder would include it all in one file? The only reason I can think of is so you have less files to deal with copying/losing if you're unfamiliar with how it exports data.

Comment: You should search the project for all the `#include` directives for that header. It should only be included in one `.c` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only **declare** the variable in your header as following -

```
extern si5351a_revb_register_t const si5351a_revb_registers[SI5351A_REVB_REG_CONFIG_NUM_REGS];
```

And in one of the C file (that usually takes ownership of the variable), you **define** the variable like you have done now.

```
si5351a_revb_register_t const si5351a_revb_registers  [SI5351A_REVB_REG_CONFIG_NUM_REGS] =
{
    { 0x0002, 0x53 },
    { 0x0003, 0x00 },
    { 0x0007, 0x00 },

    ... bunch of data
};
```

This file should also include the header which is included elsewhere.

You have correctly identified the problem. Since the header is included by multiple C files, all are defining the same variable and the linker is conflicting.